# maximizing the result of a minimizing mixed integer program

Tags: optimization, reference-request, integer-programming

I have a problem, where I need to construct an investment proposal $P$ from a variety of investment instruments, subject to some constraints. I am able to formulate the selection as a mixed-integer problem (MIP) and solve it using Python's `mip` package.

Then, from this problem, I am extracting the worst possible sub-selection portfolio $W$ subject to constraints, which can also be formulated and solved as a MIP.

I can do this on a data set, but what I would really like is to find the investment proposal, which would yield the best possible worst-case portfolio. This ends up something like a max-min problem, where both max and min steps can be expressed as MIPs.

More formally, if $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the set of all possible proposals, and $\Omega(P)$ denotes the set of all possible selections from the proposal $P \in \mathcal{P}$, and $V:\Omega(P) \to \mathbb{R}$ denotes the evaluation of the selection portfolio, we would like to
$$
\max_{P \in \mathcal{P}} \min_{s \in \Omega(P)} V(s).
$$

One super-dumb way to implement this is to run minimization, which solves 2 MIPs at each iteration, which is both extremely slow and not necessarily so well-defined, since at any step, either of the MIPs may be infeasible.

Is there a way to tackle this more intelligently? I am asking for both references and advice, if possible, please.

---

**POSSIBLY RELATED QUESTIONS**

- [A Mixed Integer Model with Mixed Integer sub-Problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681115/a-mixed-integer-model-with-mixed-integer-sub-problems)

---

**UPDATE**

Given a set of investment instruments and some grouping criteria (by longevity or by riskiness, for example), I can select a proposal which would minimize the cost of the resulting combination with some distribution in each sub-group. Then from this proposal, I select a portfolio of smaller size and other more strict rules.

E.g. if my proposal has 10 apples (at \$4 each) and 20 bananas (at \$2 each), I may create a sub-selection that will be between \$20 and \$25 and will have maximum weight or best nutritional content.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the uncertainty in your problem data, robust optimization approaches might be helpful.  It would help if you told us more about your particular problem.

Comment: @BrianBorchers please see the update, not sure what kind of details you are looking for, added a high level description

Comment: In what form are you given the function $V(S)$?

Comment: @BrianBorchers everything is linear using integer variables, both $V(s)$ and the constraints describing $\Omega(P)$ and $P \in \mathcal{P}$ -- these latter ones are both polyhedra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing a [bilevel optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilevel_optimization) problem.  One approach is to use [Benders decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benders_decomposition).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I found this useful but too general. I am sure there should be a much better solution using linearity of both problems. Accepting because there are no other alternatives.